# Iteration update in grouped pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

So I have a pyspark dataframe, which has column 'user_id', 'event_type', 'status'and 'date'

For each user_id, I want to check the number of failure for each event type.

for example, when event type is 'login', if the previous 'login' has status of '1', then  the number of failure for this  row is 0. if the previous 'login' has status of '2', then  the number of failure for this  row is equal to the number of failure of previous 'login' + 1.

for events that occurs for the first time, the number of failure can be set to 0.for example, the number of failure for the first 'login' is 0.

To solve this problem, i tried to use df.groupby ,and then go through each row to update number of failure based on previous status and previous number of failure. but since the data is too big.It takes forever.What is the optimal way to do such task in pyspark? Thanks for help !